# Turn basic wordpress search into wp-ecommerce search allowing 'product tag search'

Tags: wordpress

Novice programmer here.  Thanks for any help...

I am working with wp-ecommerce plugin for wordpress:

I would like to be able to search for product tags.

I know wordpress search does not automatically search for tags associated with a blog post.  For some reason, the wp-ecommerce search widget does not work.  Even if it did, it still does not search for product tags... to my knowledge.

Here is my current custom search.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php if (is_type_page()) continue; ?>

<div id="cat-products-container">
    <h1><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for "%s"', 'kandice' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
    <div id="cat-products-internal-container">
    <ul class="block">
    <?php $i=1 ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php 
        if (is_int($i/4)){
        echo '<li class="right">';
        } else {
        echo '<li>';
        }
    ?>

    <a href="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>">
        <img style="width:<?php echo get_option('product_image_width'); ?>px;height:<?php echo get_option('product_image_height'); ?>px" class="product_image" id="product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" alt="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_thumbnail(); ?>" />
            <div class="animated-product-info-container">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>"><?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="description-container">
                        <p><?php echo wpsc_the_product_description(); ?><a class="details-links" href="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>"></a></p>
                    </div><!--description-container-->
        </div><!--animated-product-info-container-->
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php $i++ ?>                           
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php else : ?>
        <h2 class="no-search-results">No search results found.</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!--close cat-products-internal-container-->
</div> <!--close cat-products-container-->
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Be nice, he is new. Tell him why you downvoted! Try and reinclude your question and point people exactly to the problem. For example, `How can I make my query filter on tags?`

Comment: Thank you sherman for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

See the WP_Query reference. You can query on tags.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

```
//return for one tag
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag=cooking' );

//return for multiple tags
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag=bread,baking' );
```

There are more example in the codex.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not using the WP-e-Commerce cart plugin (not anymore, anyway), I am have the same problem going on with the WooCommerce cart plugin.. The base issue here is that 'product_tag' (apparently it's the same term title in WooCommerce as it is in WP-eCommerce) is a custom taxonomy term, not a standard post tag. I found a solution in this other StackOverflow thread about the matter:

[How to amend wordpress search so it queries taxonomy terms and category terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491828/how-to-amend-wordpress-search-so-it-queries-taxonomy-terms-and-category-terms)

The code example by [tkelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526258/tkelly) worked for me when replacing the term `author` in his example with `product_tag` as per our needs for the cart plugins.