# Wordpress include post associated to specific term in search results

Tags: mysql, wordpress, search, filtering, taxonomy

I'm working on a custom search engine for my WordPress site. The DB for the project is pretty big ( 300k+ posts ) so performance is key.

I have a searchbar returning posts ('clients' & 'professionnels') and i'm trying to limit search results to post title and terms name from 'specialites' taxonomy. So far i'm using a filter (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59537500/19181295).

```
function and_extend_search( $search, &$wp_query ) {

global $wpdb;

if ( empty( $search ))
    return $search;

$terms = $wp_query->query_vars[ 's' ];
$exploded = explode( ' ', $terms );
if( $exploded === FALSE || count( $exploded ) == 0 )
    $exploded = array( 0 => $terms );

$search = '';

foreach( $exploded as $tag ) {
    $search .= " AND (
        ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$tag%')

        OR EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM 
                $wpdb->term_relationships 
            LEFT JOIN 
                $wpdb->terms 
            ON 
                $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id
            WHERE
                    $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%$tag%'
                AND
                    $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
        )
    )";
}

return $search;
```

}
add_filter('posts_search', 'and_extend_search', 500, 2);

The filter is pretty good but it's searching inside all taxonomies. What i want is keeping the filter but only return results in terms associated with 'specialites' taxonomy.

Can you guys help me please ? :)

**from Comment**

```
CREATE TABLE xmo_term_relationships (
    object_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    term_taxonomy_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    term_order int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    PRIMARY KEY (object_id,term_taxonomy_id), 
    KEY term_taxonomy_id (term_taxonomy_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are big and you want performance,

- Do not use `LIKE` with leading wildcards
- Do consider using `FULLTEXT` index(es).
- Do install this plugin: [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)
- Get rid of the second `if` statement; $exploded will be as you want it anyway.
- Try to avoid `ORs`; they do not Optimize well.

After you have done those, come back with some revised queries; I will probably have more suggestions.  At that time, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Here's my show create table : xmo_term_relationships CREATE TABLE `xmo_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
  KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: And my EXPLAIN : EXPLAIN xmo_term_relationships;

object_id bigint(20) unsigned NO PRI 0  
term_taxonomy_id bigint(20) unsigned NO PRI 0  
term_order int(11) NO  0

Comment: @Kqereda - Sorry, I meant `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`