# Wordpress - limit search results to post title and specific taxonomy name

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

I'm working on a modified vanilla WordPress search form. The form is searching for 'clients' posts. Vanilla wordpress form search inside title and content of posts. I want to change that.

I tried differents plugins (Relevanssi, searchwp, ajax search pro) none of these fit my needs because the form is way more complexe than what it seems (auto-complete, suggest, results based on localisation). So the solution need to be plugin less.

My search form look like this

```
<form action="/" method="get" id="projet-search" role="search">

    <div>
        <input class="search-field" name="s" id="nom" type="text" maxlength="256">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="clients">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">Search</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

What i have right now : Form return **'clients'** search is limited to **post title** or **all taxonomy** using https://stackoverflow.com/a/59537500/11736798

The behavior i want is : Form return **'clients**' and limit search to **post title** or **'specialites' taxonomy**

Is there a way to do this ?

Have a wonderful day you amazing peoples :)

Comment: The solution you are referring to, JOINs the `terms` and `term_relationships` tables. Try to add a WHERE condition, that limits `term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id` to the one specific ID of your "specialities" taxonomy.

Comment: I'm not sure how one can dot that. Can you explain a little more please ? :)

Comment: The solution you are referring to, has a WHERE clause checking two conditions already ... add a third one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply use any search plugin and you can set custom posts and taxonomies for search and it will only show results from those custom posts and taxonomies that you have selected.

[Ajax search lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/) also offers this feature.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! I edited my main post to add informations on my needs. I want to do it myself and not use a plugin. The search form is way more complex than what it seem ( autocomplete, suggest, use localisation data, etc...). And none of the plugins i tried fit my needs (Relevanssi, searchWP, ajax search pro ).